# Ajax content "diff", to utilise animation of new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a panel on my site, with a list of items in it.

Above that is a filter form.  As users check/uncheck checkboxes the list of items in the panel changes.  Some new ones appear, some disappear.  You get the picture.

I do this with a simple ajax call, that replaces the entire contents of the relevant `<div>` with its response.

What I'd LIKE to do, is have a bit of code that "diffs" the contents of the panel and the new ajax content.

E.g, current:

```
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
```

New:

```
<li>foo</li>
<li>hello world</li>
<li>bar>
<li>blah</li>
```

The `<li>hello world</li>` and `<li>blah</li>` items are new.

I'd like to then add those new items into the HTML, utilising an animation of some sort.  Fade in, etc, that sort of thing.

Do jQuery or similar offer this functionality, or would I need to roll my own?